Why do I keep getting an error 400 - salesforce REST API
I'm trying something pretty simple: Get customer data from my salesforce playgroubd through an API call. I was following a tutorial and here the first step was to generate an access token.
I did it exactly like the tutorial suggestet, but I keep getting an error 400.
Here is the code:
from consumer_details import CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, USERNAME, PASSWORD
import requests
import pandas as pd

DOMAIN = 'https://myplaygroundname.trailblaze.my.salesforce.com'

payload = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': CONSUMER_KEY,
    'client_secret': CONSUMER_SECRET,
    'username': USERNAME,
    'password': PASSWORD
}

oauth_endpoint = '/services/oauth2/token'
response = requests.post(DOMAIN + oauth_endpoint, data=payload)

print(response)

I checked my credentials, domain etc. and they're all correct and correctly written.
Probably pretty easy to fix, but I'm new to this!
Any ideas? Thanks!

From the https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5 I see that there should be no body in the auth request but a bunch of params in the url itself. Try this request with Postman or smth similar.

You should try to append security token to your password.
